# Spring MVC redirect with variables

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect, spring-data

I have following Spring MVC 3.2.4 method:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/products/{product}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(Product product, @Valid @ModelAttribute("productForm") ProductForm productForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "products/view";
    }
    mapper.map(productForm, product);
    productService.saveProduct(product);
    return "redirect:/products/{product}";
}
```

After success it should redirect back user to detail of product. Problem is that instead of redirecting to page "/products/1" I am redirected to page "/products/Product [code=1234567890, name=Nejaky]". It looks like placeholder {product} is replaced by product.toString() instead of original ID from URL.
I am using built-in Spring Data converter:

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />

<bean class="org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter">
    <constructor-arg ref="conversionService" />
</bean>
```

What should I do to make it work correctly and redirect me back to "/products/1" without doing things like "redirect:/product" + product.getId()?

Comment: Do you have an attribute named "product" in your model perhaps via ModelAttribute annotated method?

Answer (score 1):

Our story starts in `RedirectView` source code, in the method `replaceUriTemplateVariables`.

```
protected StringBuilder replaceUriTemplateVariables(
        String targetUrl, Map<String, Object> model, Map<String, String> currentUriVariables, String encodingScheme)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher m = URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLE_PATTERN.matcher(targetUrl);
    int endLastMatch = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        String name = m.group(1);
        Object value = model.containsKey(name) ? model.remove(name) : currentUriVariables.get(name);
        Assert.notNull(value, "Model has no value for '" + name + "'");
        result.append(targetUrl.substring(endLastMatch, m.start()));
        result.append(UriUtils.encodePathSegment(value.toString(), encodingScheme));
        endLastMatch = m.end();
    }
    result.append(targetUrl.substring(endLastMatch, targetUrl.length()));
    return result;
}
```

As you had predicted, the method uses `value.toString()` where `value` is your `product` object in the `Model`. No other component like a conversion system is involved here. Your options are as follows:

Use

```
"redirect:/product" + product.getId()
```

Add a model attribute called `"productId"` and use that in your view name

```
model.addAttribute("productId", product.getId());
"redirect:/product/{productId}"
```

Or use uri variables. I don't have information on those yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally found reason for this. I had to annotate product param with @PathVariable. Wondering that it worked without it.

Comment: In this particular case, maybe, because product object ended up in the model and then that got used when string was replaced, but in general you don't even have to have product as an argument in the handler method for replacing of {product} to work in redirect string.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but for anyone facing the same problem here is the answer

Just inject RedirectAttributes  to your controller and use `redirectAtrr.addAttribute([attrbuteName],[attributeValue])`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products/{product}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(Product product,@Valid,@ModelAttribute("productForm") ProductForm productForm,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model,RedirectAttributes redirectAttr) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "products/view";
    }
    mapper.map(productForm, product);
    productService.saveProduct(product);
    redirectAttr.addAttributte("productId",product.getId());
    return "redirect:/products/{productId}";
}
```

Read [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) for more understanding.