# How to pass @SessionAttributes value between controllers

Tags: spring-boot, session

> My first controller is Login

---

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("session")
public class LoginController extends GlobalController {

      @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String indexAction() throws IOException {
            return "login";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method= RequestMethod.POST)
        public String indexAction(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password,HttpSession session) {
          String page = "login";
           if(username != "" && password != ""){
              try {
                  if(userService.authenticationUser(username,password) == "success"){
                      page = "redirect:/main";
                      session.setAttribute("test","Salom");

                      //this.httpSession =session;
                      //System.out.println(session.getAttribute("test"));
                  }
                  else page = "login";
               }
              catch (Exception e){
                  e.fillInStackTrace();
              }
           }
          else page = "login";
          return page;
        }



    }
```

> My second Controller is Test

---

```
package com.springboot.app.controllers.reports;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@SessionAttributes("session")
public class TestController {

       @RequestMapping(value = "/test",method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String index(){
           @SessionAttributes("session")HttpSession session;
           return "";
       }



}
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- How to pass @SessionAttributes("session") from login Controller to Test controller or how to store @SessionAttributes("session") in variable

Answer (score 0):

@SessionAttributes is not intended to be used (and will not work also) to store objects in the session between different controllers. The controller annotated with @SessionAttributes must also tell that it is finished (so controllerA not ControllerB). The model message from controller a is still not available for controller B.

see [this conversation](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/114053-sessionattributes-and-two-controllers)

Comment: can you help me how to store some variable value and pass variable value between controllers

Comment: you can use redirection approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280718/spring-mvc-redirect-with-variables

Answer (score 0):

you can pass from LoginController to TestController:

```
e.g. Username = name

LoginController:

import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("name")
public class LoginController{

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showWelcomePage(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String password){

        boolean isValidUser = service.validateUser(name, password);

        if (!isValidUser) {
            model.put("errorMessage", "Invalid Credentials");
            return "login";
        }

        model.put("name", name);
        model.put("password", password);

        return "welcome";


TestController:

@SessionAttributes("name")

public void showUsername(ModelMap model){
    System.out.println("Username is: " + (String) model.get("name");
}


}

hope there is no typo!
```